# Passing Json to Action using jquery MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am populating data using Model on UI, and adding more textbox on UI dynamically so that i can update the new list in db.

Problem 1: the Model does not bind the value of new fields generated using js and returns the same original value.

So i tried to read the Model value as json and updated it with new textbox value and calling an action using jquery ajax call.

but i am unable to get the object under Action.

Also suggest if it's possible without calling it through Ajax.

## HTML

```
<label asp-for="Steps"></label>
@foreach (var item in Model.Steps)
{
    <div id="step" class="even-Spread">
        <input asp-for="@item.lines" class="form-control text-box in-line ui-autocomplete-input col-md-Field" id="test_lines" />

        <button id="removeRow" type="button" class="btn btn-danger  btn-sm">X</button>
        <button id="addRow" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">+</button>
    </div>
}


<script>
 $(document).on('click', '#sbt', function () {

     var steps = [
         { "id": 1, "lines": "LoginPage.LoginApollo(UserRole.Sales);", "ScriptsId": 1010, "testName": "Creating new test cses qwerreee" },
         { "id": 2, "lines": "LoginPage.LoginApollo(UserRole.Sales);", "ScriptsId": 1010, "testName": "Creating new test cses qwerreee" },
         { "id": 3, "lines": "LoginPage.LoginApollo(UserRole.Sales);", "ScriptsId": 1010, "testName": "Creating new test cses qwerreee" }
     ]

     var data = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(@Model));
     data.steps = steps;
     console.log(data);

     var items = JSON.stringify(data);

     $.ajax({
         url: '/Scripts/EditTestCasesCustom',
         type: 'POST',
         data: items,
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (data) {
             alert(data);
         }
     });
 });
</script>



    public class Scripts
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string TestCaseName { get; set; }
        public List<Step>? Steps { get; set; }
        public string? User { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    }  
    public class Step
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string lines { get; set; }
        public int ScriptsId { get; set; }
        public string TestName { get; set; }
    }


     [HttpPost]
     public async Task<IActionResult> EditTestCasesCustom(Scripts scripts)
     {

         return View(scripts);

     }
```

my webpage look like this, below record was created and user trying to update the record.
[image: webpage]